# Error while updating debug log trace flag

Tags: debugging, debug, stacktrace, apex-debugger

I am trying to update the debug log trace flag for my user but getting the following error

> Having an active trace flag triggers debug logging. You have 259 MB of the maximum 250 MB of debug logs. Before you can edit trace flags, delete some debug logs.

I have removed all existing debug logs but it is still throwing the error.

Answer (score 115, accepted):

I have faced this issue, which I fixed it by deleting all debugs logs from developer console.

1. In dev console, Select tab "Query Editor" at the bottom of the console
2. Select check box "Use Tooling API"
3. Use this query:

   ```
   SELECT Id FROM ApexLog
   ```
4. Delete all rows (Use shift key to select all rows)

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000194045&type=1

Once all rows are deleted you will be able to save new debug logs.

**Update** : Salesforce has released a video tutorial for same. https://youtu.be/rwORE5T39C4

Comment: The moment I click on delete the whole system hangs. Is there is any solution to this. We have around 2000 apex logs rows in org

Comment: @MonalisaDas do in cunks by having a limit

`SELECT Id FROM ApexLog LIMIT 200' and then delete

Comment: This worked for me.  However...having to do it this way makes me cringe.  This functionality should have been built into the Debug -> Clear menu.  I know Salesforce is moving to VS Code and scratch orgs but I still use dev console for running test suites, so it sucks to have logs "fill up" like that.

Comment: +1 nice!!......

Comment: FYI: One thing I noticed using this solution is that I had to stay in the developer console for a while while the logs deleted. I clicked the "refresh grid" button intermittently to get an update of how many log records had been deleted thus far, and waited until it reached zero. Refreshing the entire page caused problems that lead to me having to start the process over again.

Comment: I found this to be much easier with the Salesforce Inspector extension. `SELECT ID FROM ApexLog`. Copy. Go to "Data Import". Select "Delete" operation. Paste and execute. Takes just seconds.

Answer (score 12):

The short term solution is to keep playing whack-a-<strike>mole~</strike>ApexLog as [Pranay has suggested](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/217492/102).

Longer term, the problem comes back to the Summer'18 update [Store Larger Debug Logs with Changed Log Limits](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/summer18/release-notes/rn_forcecom_debugging_log_limits.htm):

> We increased the size limit for debug logs from 2 MB per log to 5 MB. **You can store up to 250 MB of debug logs at a time.** System logs are now deleted automatically after 24 hours instead of after seven days. Monitoring logs are still saved for seven days.

This is also compounded with the Winter '18 update [Retain More Debug Logs for Longer](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/winter18/release-notes/rn_forcecom_debugging_debug_logs.htm):

> We changed the way that we delete old debug logs. **We now retain debug logs for 7 days.** You can generate a total of 250 MB of debug logs in a 15-minute window. When your org is upgraded to Winter ’18, all logs that are at least 7 days old are deleted. This change applies to both Lightning Experience and Salesforce Classic.
>
> Previously, you could generate up to 50 MB of debug logs. We kept them indefinitely, deleting the oldest log each time that you exceeded the limit. We removed the 50 MB limit and changed to a 7-day storage limit.

A couple of releases ago you had Apex logs up to 2 MB in size with a total limit of 50 MB that would automatically drop the older logs.

Currently (Winter '18) you have logs up to 5 MB in size with a total limit of 250 MB that can stay around for up to 7 days before being automatically purged. As many are finding, in a busy org it is easy to hit that 250 MB limit in a much shorter time period than 7 days.

I've created the idea [Allow TraceFlags to indicate that Debug logs can be deleted automatically](https://ideas.salesforce.com/s/idea/a0B8W00000GdZ8bUAF/allow-traceflags-to-indicate-that-debug-logs-can-be-deleted-automatically). The idea is to give the developer/admin control how how long they need the corresponding logs to stay around for. With a TTL (Time to Live) setting on each generated log they could be cleared out automatically while still giving the flexibility to capture a few large short term logs or smaller logs with a longer life span.

Nathan Totten is the current PM for this area an is aware of the issues it is causing - https://twitter.com/ntotten/status/1007432141725224960

---

Note, I've copied this answer out of a [duplicate question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/222605/102) to here.