# Has Salesforce stopped cleaning up old debug logs?

Tags: debug-logs

Seems like every time I open the dev console these days I get this message:

> The Developer Console didn't set the DEVELOPER_LOG trace flag on your
>   user. Having an active trace flag triggers debug logging. You have 403
>   MB of the maximum 250 MB of debug logs. Before you can edit trace
>   flags, delete some debug logs.

I've had to manually query ApexLog using the Tooling API and delete the existing logs every time for new logs to start recording again.

I did hear somewhere that SF switched from a time limit on debug logs to a size limit... But is there a setting change that allows SF to go back to deleting the oldest logs when the size limit is reached?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this was a duplicate. Answer seems to be just manually deleting for now. Here is a thread with more info: [Maximum log level exceeded in Developer Console](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/222568/maximum-log-level-exceeded-in-developer-console?rq=1)