# Is it possible to turn on the Apex Replay Debugger permanently or for the entire day from VSCode

Tags: salesforcedx, salesforcedx-cli, vs-code, debugging, apex-replay-debugger

Every time I [use the VSCode command to turn on the Apex Replay Debugger](https://developer.salesforce.com/tools/vscode/en/apex/replay-debugger/), it expires in less than an hour, and then I have to re-run the command to turn it back on again. Is there a way to turn it on for the entire day or just permanently? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not permanently, as it depends on [TraceFlag](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_tooling.meta/api_tooling/tooling_api_objects_traceflag.htm), which allows a maximum of 24 hours. You could go in to Setup after enabling to extend the session (see Setup > Monitoring > Debug Logs), but keep in mind the reason why it's short to begin with is because you have a maximum storage for debug logs. Once you exceed this limit, the flag would be disabled anyways until you reduce your storage usage (you can read more about that in this [excellent answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/222605/2984)). It's probably best to turn it on when you need it, and turn it off again when you don't. Cleaning up debug logs that you never meant to create is a waste of your time.

Comment: thanks for all the additional tips and gotchas you've mentioned. I appreciate it!!

Answer (score 1):

If you use [VsCode SFDX Hardis extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=NicolasVuillamy.vscode-sfdx-hardis), activate debug logs will be automatically run when:

- you open a SFDX project in VsCode containing breakpoints
- you define a breakpoint

More info in [this article](https://medium.com/p/12237c0638b7)

[image]